# Create element and assign class in one step

Tags: javascript

Here are two ways that I know to create an element and assign it a class:

```js
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.classList.add('foo');
```

```js
const el = document.createElement('div');
foo.className = 'foo';
```

Is there a one-step solution for it? I tried

```js
const el = document.createElement('div').classList.add('foo');
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You _could_ `let el = '<div class="foo">Content here</div>';` and insert using `innerHTML` or `insertAdjacentHTML()`

Comment: You cant not chain class name addition to object that in time of creation does not exists.as per your exact code.You could create it in one go if you use it as string and  add class name in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the usual way to do it is a two-step technique, try this:

```js
const el = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), { className: 'foo' });

console.log(el);
console.log(el.className);
```

Comment: Object.assign was eye opener, but can you please say why you think "right way to do it is a two-step technique"? I can not think of any problems with this. You add property itself with value to new object, just like you would add value in 2nd step?

Answer (score 2):

You're stuck with either using an HTML string and innerHTML or trying jQuery which allows the chaining of commands, but for something so small it doesn't make sense to bring jQuery into the mix, what's the reason you needed a one-liner?

For a rough working example in vanilla js

```js
var myHTML = "<div class='hello'></div>";
document.body.innerHTML += myHTML
```